# How to keep a modal/toast on screen after form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, toast

I have a contact form, after submitting which, I want to display either an error toast or a success toast.
The problem is that although the toast appears correctly, it disappears almost instantly because the page reloads when I click 'Submit'. 
How do I make the toast stay for longer?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to serialize the form and submit it via ajax.  In the subscription you will need to do a preventDefault() call on the event being passed in.  Then call your toast in the success/fail parts of your ajax call.

As a bare bones example:

**HTML**

```
<form>
   ...Form Stuff
   ...Here

   <a class="submitButton">Submit</a>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".submitButton").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var form = $(this).parents("form:first");
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/my/url',
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function (response) {
               openToast();
          }
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you please dumb that down for me? @Nick

Comment: @VikramBajaj I added a code sample, hope that helps.  We use something similar at work since we submit almost all of our forms via ajax.

Comment: Thanks @Nick I was hoping there would be a simpler solution, because I've already used php to send the form details to my email and I'm using JavaScript to decide which toast to show. If I use preventDefault(), it could interfere with the form being sent to my email, isn't it?

Comment: Yes and no.  It will still make the call, it just won't do a page refresh.  You would need to move the PHP code that does the sending into a separate file (I believe, it's been a couple years since I used PHP).  It's a little more development work, definitely, but without doing a complete page reload I can't think of a better way.  The preventDefault() just keeps the event from bubbling up and being handled anywhere else (since you're putting in custom handling of the event).  For instance using a button with this method and without preventDefault would mean the form would be submitted twice.